# Electric phenomenon when tornado funnel disappears?

Tags: meteorology, lightning, tornado

A video of a recent tornado in Germany shows two points of glowing light appear at the end of the lifetime of a tornado, when the funnel is already almost entirely retracted. Here is [a video link](https://youtu.be/XaT6U0v6lqk?t=41). The two glowing points appear at the tip of a church tower and in the cloud, at about the given timestamp.

Is that an electric discharge, like a [St. Elmo's fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Elmo%27s_fire)? Is that common with tornadoes?